# Send email without leaving a copy in the Sent folder

Tags: c#, email, smtp, gmail, smtpclient

I am using the SmtpClient to send to new users the credentials when the Admin creates them in the System. And everytime the user itself (not the Admin) updates his Account i send an email about the new credentials in case the user changes the Username or the Password.

So what i want is not to save a copy of the sent emails in the Sent folder.

I am working with C# and developing a WPF application.

So is it possible to send an email without leaving a copy?

I am just trying to avoid leaving a copy in the Sent folder because the credentials of the all the users will be there in the Sent emails.

Thansk in advance!

Comment: Sending an email with user id and password is always unsafe. If the users email is compromised, then the person can still look into the inbox for the user id and password.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found on [Gmail forum](http://productforums.google.com/forum/#!topic/gmail/WxUrcRlGuxw)

> There is no option to not save sent messages in Gmail, but you can
>   create a filter to delete all sent mail.  Create a filter with "me" in
>   the From field, and set it to delete.  The messages will be put in the
>   Trash immediately.

Answer (score -1):

You need to send the message from Outlook (or other mail client) if you want to have the sent message in the "Sent messages" folder. This folder is an Outlook (and many other mail clients) concept, not an SMTP concept.

Comment: It's precisely the opposite what i want. I don't want to leave a copy. I am not using the Outlook to send emails but the SmtpClient object from the framework.

Comment: Since you are not using Outlook copy of messages will not be saved in the "Sent" folder.

Comment: But its happening. I am using the SmtpClient and trying with Gmail server and Gmail account credentials to send the emails. And its leaving copies of them in Sent folder in the Google account. And that is exactly what i am trying to prevent...

Comment: I understand. Gmail's SMTP server automatically saves a copy of any message you send in the Sent Items folder for you.